# User is authenticated but their data is not saved in Cloud Firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am fairly new to flutter and firebase and I've been following Reed Barger's guide to "Build a Social Network with Flutter and Firebase" https://www.udemy.com/course/build-a-social-network-with-flutter-and-firebase. I have successfully done authentication with Google but I face a problem with creating a user in Firestore. The method for that is

```
createUserInFirestore() async {
    //1) check if user exists in user's collection in database (according to their id)
    final GoogleSignInAccount user = googleSignIn.currentUser;
    final DocumentSnapshot docu = await usersRef.doc(user.id).get();
    //2) If user doesn't exist, take them to create account page
    if (!docu.exists) {
      final username = await Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CreateAccount()));

      //3)  get user name from create account and use it to create new user's document in user's collection
      usersRef.doc(user.id).set({
        "id": user.id,
        "username": username,
        "photoUrl": user.photoUrl,
        "email": user.email,
        "displayName": user.displayName,
        "bio": "",
        "timestamp": timestamp
      });
    }
  }
```

The problem is that it doesn't take a new user to the CreateAccount page and the Firestore database is also not updated. Instead, the home page is loaded and I get the error

```
E/flutter (17311): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'doc' was called on null.
E/flutter (17311): Receiver: null
E/flutter (17311): Tried calling: doc("1148131790923706651234")
```

Also, the user is not added in the Firebase Console under `Users` in `Authentication`. For now, I'm only working on Android.
Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What is a usersRef? You haven't defined it, so it is null. You are calling method 'doc' on null variable usersRef. Try something like this to initialize usersRef:

```
CollectionReference usersRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users');
```

Comment: I defined it at the top of the page. I've actually found that the problem was actually that Firebase was not initialized. Thanks